# How to integrate all td cells in table

Tags: html, css

How can I remove the space between all `<td>` in the `<table>` ?

look at this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td> one
        </td>
        <td> two
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>three
        </td>
        <td> four
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The output is something like this: ([here](https://jsfiddle.net/rubhxdm1/) is a fiddle)

```
+-----+ +----+
|one  | |two |
+-----+ +----+
+-----+ +----+
|three| |four|
+-----+ +----+
```

I want this:

```
+-----+----+
|one  |two |
+-----+----+
+-----+----+
|three|four|
+-----+----+
```

In other word, removing the space between elements of row. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Approach 1.** You can use `cellspacing` and `cellpadding` properties of table:

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
</table>
```

Here is the [JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/rubhxdm1/1/).

**Approach 2.** Use CSS `border-collapse` property. It looks more beautiful and it is more modern:

> The border-collapse property sets whether the table borders are
>   collapsed into a single border or detached as in standard HTML.

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Here is the [second JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/rubhxdm1/3/).

Comment: That's weird, I searched too much before asking, but I did not fount anything, anyway thanks. +1 voteup.

Comment: ok well, suppose a column has not any value (content), but the width of that column is not zero [(it is almost `1px`)](https://jsfiddle.net/rubhxdm1/5/), why ? how can remove it ?

Comment: @Sajad Oh, probably, it is kind of minimal size. You can hide this `td`, for example using CSS selector `:empty`. Look at [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rubhxdm1/6/). Notice that `td` should be absolutely empty then (td with new line is not empty). But why do you need this?

Comment: I need to something like stackoverflow comments, the number of vote comment is a `<td>`, and it is hide, when I give a voteup to a comment it will be show.

Answer (score 2):

Add below code in your css :-

```
table{
cellpadding:"0";
}
```

The cellpadding attribute specifies the space, in pixels, between the cell wall and the cell content.

[For more reading](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_table_cellpadding.asp)

Comment: ok well, suppose a column has not any value (content), but the width of that column is not zero [(it is almost 1px)](https://jsfiddle.net/rubhxdm1/5/), why ? how can remove it ?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```css
table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border-spacing: 0; 
}
td{
    border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td> one
        </td>
        <td> two
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>three
        </td>
        <td> four
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```